# Read Empty cell in DatagridView in C#

Tags: c#

I have one datagridview with 2 columns. Column 1 may have random filled cells. I want to run a code for read all cell I tried this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0] != null 
            && this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1] != null)
        {
            str1 = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            str2 = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i++].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            if (str1 != str2)
            {//Some code will be here}` 
            .....
```

But the loop is terminating after reading any empty cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
{
 if (this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0] != null  && this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1] !=null)
  {
   for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
     if(this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
      {
     str1 = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
      }
     if(str2 = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i++].Cells[0].Value != null)
     {
     str2 = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i++].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
     }
     if (str1 != str2)
     {//Some code will be here
     }//if condition end
    }//if condition end 
  }//for loop end 
 }//for loop end
```

If you are checking and assigning any value in the cell you've to check the null, if it is not null then only you can convert it to the string. if you try to convert the null value to the string using .ToString() it will raise an exception.

The above code is modified please try for the removing the duplicates in the grid view content

Comment: Use Convert.toString() to handle `NULL` and compare with "" (Empty String)